# failed Pipeline #xxx triggered 2 hours ago by User User validation required

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to push my local branch to gitlab. The branch is pushed but a red cross icon is shown on right hand side saying "Pipeline xxxx failed". It is also asking to validate my account with debit/credit card or run with new runners.
Not able to merge my branch to other branches. I am new to gitlab.
Please suggest if anyone knows anything about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved by removing dist or say build folder from my commits to git.
Gitlab has modified pipeline rules to control crypto mining.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent crypto [mining](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/05/17/prevent-crypto-mining-abuse/) with their pipelines in the free tier, from the 17th of May 2021 onward, all new users need to provide their credit card details for pipeline usage.

When did you open your gitlab account?

Comment: May 19th, 2021 and validated with card details as well.